# Supplying multiple devices from one battery

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging, power-electronics

For my project, I'm planning to charge a battery using solar power. The battery is 12V. After it is charged, it will provide power to the following:

1. 6v to the arduino
2. 12v to a coin acceptor
3. 5v 1A to 10 devices.

I'm confused and don't know where to start, could anyone suggest any books, links, or methods which could help me in doing this.....

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with powering the coin acceptor directly from the battery, although the battery voltage will be a bit more than 12V if you charge it fully. Check the **data sheet** of the coin acceptor and the battery, to determine if the coin acceptor will be able to tolerate the max battery voltage.

The Arduino doesn't use much power, so you can use a **linear volage regulator** to power it. These are small, cheap and simple, but if you try to push too much current through them, they will get very hot. By the way, why do you need 6V for the Arduino? Can you not run it on 5V?

For the "5V 1A to 10 devices", do you mean 1A to each device, in other words 10A total, or do you mean 1A total? In either case, a **buck converter** (aka **step-down converter**) is probably the most appropriate tool for the job. Or you could use ten smaller buck converters, one for each device.

I bolded some keywords for you. If you google these phrases, you should be able to find the information that you need to get on with your project.

Comment: well the recommended supply voltage for the arduino is 7-12 V on the website. I though that the 5V output i get may not be exact so i decided to increase it to 6V to feed the arduino with sufficient power. According to the website it is not advised to supply the arduino with a voltage higher than 12V.                                                                                      I meant one amp to each device.(mobile phones)                                                                                  Thanks for the hint on the max battery thing. I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and recommendations, any further advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things that need to be cleared up before you begin:

1. What type of battery is it? This will determine how you will be able to charge it
2. What is the voltage output of your solar panel? This will determine what additional components you need to charge the battery.
3. Do you plan on supplying 1A to each device, or .1A? This will determine the feasibility of your scenario
4. Is this a prototype where costs/components are less relevant, or a production device?

Since I don't know the answer to point 1, I'm going to skip ahead. I am also going to assume this is for a prototype

For point 2: if your solar panel outputs a small voltage, you will need to use a boost-converter to supply a higher voltage to the battery charging circuit.

For point 3: assuming it's feasible, use a buck converter to bring the voltage down to 5V from 12. You will need to choose the appropriate one that can handle your current requirements (if it's 10A that you're trying to draw)

Lastly, for Arduino you can use a standard voltage regulator, and if your coin acceptor needs precise 12V input, then you can use a voltage regulator for that, as well.

EDIT: for reference designs and use-cases, I recommend using Sparkfun and Adafruit. For example: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9370 is pretty much what you need for the switching regulator. You can buy those and plug-n-play, or see their designs and fabricate your own PCBs.

P.S. You probably do not need 6V for Arduino; you can use the 5V and plug it into the USB (or one of the pins, IIRC)

Comment: 1. Planning to  use a  12V VRLA battery, charging it using an MPPT charge controller. 2 50 W Solar panel is rated at 12 v. 3.One amp to each device(planning to charge mobile phones). 4. Well costs are relevant i'm on a budget.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice and recommendations, any further advice will be appreciated. I'll try and research more on the arduino thing. . One more thing . when i try to go to the next line by pressing enter, my comment will automatically enter so how do i go to the next line?. (Silly question sorry ..)